# Add to favourites from console at a cloud9 ssh workspace

Tags: ssh, workspace, cloud9-ide, favorites

How can i add to Favorites a folder from console at a cloud9 ssh workspace supposing i have installed c9 dependencies as root under /root/.c9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible at the moment. Here's what you *can* show though:

- Home folder (Just click on the gear in the file navigation and select "Show Home in Favorites")
- FTP Mount points also show up under Favourites (https://c9.io/site/blog/2014/12/ftp-sftp-mounting-beta)
- Any file within your project (by right-clicking and selecting 'Add to Favorites')

Hope that helps!